# Python - Pairwise count items

Tags: python, pandas

Hello there ^^  I'm working on this stuff for 2days and I couldn't find a solution.

---

In kaggle.com there is a Brazilian ecommerce public dataset of orders of Olist Store. Go to following link and download the dataset. https://www.kaggle.com/olistbr/brazilian-ecommerce. Note that the data is distributed to multiple csv files. Using this dataset do the following analysis.

Here, we will find the economic interaction between cities. We will find the total number of orders between cities. Meaning, economic interaction between city pair "sao paulo" and "rio de janeiro" is the sum of number of orders which "sao paulo" as the customer city and "rio de janeiro" as the seller city, and the opposite ("sao paulo" as the seller city and "rio de janeiro" as the customer city). After calculating economic interaction for each city pair return the top-10 cities having the highest interactions in terms of the number of total orders.

The function in your solution should take folder of the dataset as the input.  Hint: When merging files, you can use the following order:

data=pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.merge(order_items,products),product_translation),or ders),sellers),customers)

I tried to use Groupby function as-

```
data.groupby(['seller_city','customer_city'],as_index = False).count().reset_index('Count')
```

---

### Tl;dr

As you can see below, there is two column called col1 and col2. There are some transactions from col1 to col2. I want to count each transaction. I

But it gives me a wrong output.

Input:

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c','d'], 'col2':['b','b','a','a','d','c']})
```

Output should be :

```
pd.DataFrame({'a-b':[2],'b-a':[2],'c-d':[1],'d-c':[1] })
```

Comment: what is the output that it is giving you?  Also consider pairing down your question. We don't want to read through your whole homework assignment

Comment: Yeah sorry i forgot to upload my code's output and the answer....
https://imgur.com/a/bdOG6Q5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
b['col3'] = (b['col1'] + '-' + b['col2'])
print(b.groupby('col3').size())
```

Output:

```
a-b    2
b-a    2
c-d    1
d-c    1
```

**EDIT 1**

Based on your input data (as in comments), here is the df I made up and the results

Code:

```
df[['seller_city','customer_city']]
```

Output:

```
            seller_city         customer_city
0         volta redonda  sao jose dos pinhais
1         volta redonda  sao jose dos pinhais
2  sao jose dos pinhais         volta redonda
```

Code:

```
df.groupby((df['seller_city'] + '-' + df['customer_city'])).size()
```

Output:

```
sao jose dos pinhais-volta redonda    1
volta redonda-sao jose dos pinhais    2
```

Comment: I tried this but the output is not correct. I upload the answer and my code's output in the comment. I'm started to think the answer is wrong.

Comment: I suppose this is the expected output you have in your question. What is the issue you are facing? Can you post the an extract of your data frame and your expected result? Do not post images, it will be hard for us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The dataframe consists -> order_id,order_item_id,product_id,seller_id 
shipping_limit_date,price,freight_value,product_category_name,product_name_lenght,product_description_lenght,product_photos_qty
product_weight_g,product_length_cm,product_height_cm
product_width_cm,product_category_name_english
customer_id,order_status,order_purchase_timestamp
order_approved_at,order_delivered_carrier_date,order_delivered_customer_date 
order_estimated_delivery_date,seller_zip_code_prefix 
seller_city,seller_state,customer_unique_id,customer_zip_code_prefix
customer_city,customer_state

Comment: And I want to count pairwise seller_city and customer_city. I tried to use
data.groupby(['seller_city','customer_city'],as_indexfalse).count().reset_index('Count')

Comment: Did you try this? `df.groupby((df['seller_city'] + '-' + df['customer_city'])).size()`

Comment: What you have given here is the columns of your data frame, not the data

Comment: Yes i tried it. It gives the same result. Maybe the answer sheet has a problem

Comment: 6f8c31653edb8c83e1a739408b5ff750 1 4244733e06e7ecb4970a6e2683c13e61 48436dade18ac8b2bce089ec2a041202 2017-08-07 18:55:08 58.9 16.17 cool_stuff 58.0 598.0 4.0 650.0 28.0 9.0 14.0 cool_stuff 30407a72ad8b3f4df4d15369126b20c9 delivered 2017-08-01 18:38:42 2017-08-01 18:55:08 2017-08-02 19:07:36 2017-08-09 21:26:33 2017-08-25 00:00:00 27277 volta redonda SP e7c828d22c0682c1565252deefbe334d 83070 sao jose dos pinhais PR

Comment: This is the one row of the data

Comment: Using this one row that you gave, I got the result using `df.groupby((df['seller_city'] + '-' + df['customer_city'])).size()`. Result: `volta redonda-sao jose dos pinhais    1`. "volta redonda" is the seller city and "sao jose dos pinhais" is the customer city and the count of this combination is 1.

Comment: See EDIT 1, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you again I guess the answer sheet is incorrect. Your code and mine have the same output. I appreciate your work and helping